# Copy the Result Set Into another table

Tags: sql, select-into

I just want to copy the result set of this query into another table using Java:

```
 select basescore, count(*) from log 
 group by basescore     ;;;;;suppose________INTO log2 FROM log
```

I have tried a lot but it gives me errors can anybody help please. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select basescore, count(*) cnt 
into log2
from log     
group by basescore
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to SQL Server so nice of you! hats off

Answer (score 0):

You don't need java for that. You can do this in one query

```
insert into log2 (score_column, count_column)
select basescore, count(*)
from log 
group by basescore
```